# Plugin service and variable

Tags: craft3

I have a service called `useTR.php`. It has a public method `exampleService()`.

In the variables folder I have added the following code in my `KGVariable.php` (KG is my plugin name)

```
public function sayHello() {
    return craft()->useTR->exampleService();
}
```

In my templates folder I have an html that gets loaded after a form submission and that html has the following code.

```
<p>Thank you {{ craft.KG.sayHello() }} will contact you soon</p>
```

When this HTML is loaded, I get the following error:

> Twig Runtime Error – Twig_Error_Runtime
>   Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::keyword()

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help (I am a beginner at Craft). Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Craft 3 or Craft 2. The code is for Craft 2 but the exception for Craft 3. It's likely you are using the wrong code. Furthermore the exception is not really related to your code. You might want to take a look at pluginfactory.io - it creates the entire structure with example code for you

Comment: I am using Craft 3. I created the entire structure using pluginfactory.io. Do you see any issue with the way I am writing the code, I mean any obvious issue.

Comment: Yes it's for Craft 2 and not Craft 3. There is no `craft()` function in v3

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here, but a) assuming you're really using Craft 3 and b) you generated your plugin, service and variable scaffolding on https://pluginfactory.io, this should work:

`KGVariable.php` Variable

```
<?php

namespace kg\variables;

class KGVariable
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return \kg\KG::$plugin->useTR->exampleService();
    }
}
```

`UseTR.php` Service

```
<?php

namespace kg\services;

use craft\base\Component;

class UseTR extends Component
{
    public function exampleService()
    {
        $result = 'hello';
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then using this in a template will return `hello`:

```
{{ craft.kG.sayHello() }}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:

Comment: Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::keyword()

Comment: You've got something going on somewhere else, then. The string `keyword` isn't in any of the code posted above or generated by pluginfactory.io.